# Replace an email in all commits inside a git repository

Tags: git

I have a lot of commit with an email that is not valid. I want to replace all instances of this email with a correct one. Really, I need to completely remove an author replacing it with another one. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, although rewriting history is not a good use case, if you are sharing the git repository with other contributors. Check this post [Change the author and committer name and e-mail of multiple commits in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/change-the-author-of-a-commit-in-git) for more detailed info.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to rewriting history, as has been otherwise pointed out, git provides a mechanism for changing which name and/or email address is displayed without changing history, avoiding the problems which that brings.

You can create a `.mailmap` file in the root of the workdir which provides a mapping from the old or wrong e-mail address to the correct one. You can write

```
<correct@example.com> <wrong@email>
```

in the file and git-log will show the correct email. Check out [git help shortlog](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog) for more information